# Oracle SQL, using the count function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having great difficulty with a particular select statement involving count.  What I am supposed to do is:

For each movie category, now project the movie category name, and the number of videos of movies in that category.

```
select category_name, count(movie_num)
from movie, movie_category
where movie.category_code = movie_category.category_code
group by category_name;
```

While this statement produces some results, it does not project the correct number of results.  What I get from the above statement:

```
CATEGORY_N COUNT(MOVIE_NUM)
---------- ----------------
Action                    7
Classic                   4
Family                    4
Drama                     4
Comedy                    1
```

Although you can't see my tables, hopefully these will give you an idea of what they are:

```
Movie(MOVIE_NUM, movie_title, movie_director_lname, movie_yr_released, movie_rating,
category_code)
foreign key(category_code) references movie_category

Movie_category(CATEGORY_CODE, category_name)
```

In the end, this is what I should be getting:

```
CATEGORY_N   COUNT(*)                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
Action             20                                                           
Family             10                                                           
Classic             6                                                           
Drama               5                                                           
Comedy              1
```

But I cannot figure it out. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: what happens when you change `count(movie_num)` to `count(*)`?

Comment: Are you sure that the column `movie_num` is `not null` and `primary key`? Can you post the DDL script of the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOVIE_NUM may contains null values.

Use

```
SELECT category_name, COUNT (*)
  FROM movie, movie_category
 WHERE movie.category_code = movie_category.category_code
GROUP BY category_name;
```

or

```
SELECT category_name, COUNT (NVL (movie_num, 1))
  FROM movie, movie_category
 WHERE movie.category_code = movie_category.category_code
GROUP BY category_name;
```